# When do pairs of quarks form jets vs mesons?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, hadronization

For certain processes with low momentum transfer, such as the Kaon decay shown below, quarks will form bound states of mesons.

[image]

Whereas for higher momentum-transfer processes, such as the decay of an on-shell heavy particle to a quark-anti-quark pair, you expect the quarks to instead hadronize to form either a pair of hadronic jets or a single large-$R$ jet. My question is what precisely determines this behaviour. Consider as an example the decay of a new right-handed neutrino $N$, which occurs via an off-shell $W$. For the $W \rightarrow qq$ decay channel, when would we expect this to give $N \rightarrow l \pi$ and when would we expect $N \rightarrow ljj$ ($j$ here meaning jet)? I know that it involves some relation between the momentum transfer and the QCD scale, but the precise criteria are not clear to me.

[image]

Comment: the kaon **is** a  bound state of the quark antiquark pair, as far as our models in mainstream physics go, whereas the W is modeled as a point particle with the mass of W that decays into constituents., and neutrinos do not decay, as they have very small mass, and there would not be enough energy in their center of mass .

Comment: also how could there be quantum number conservation?

Comment: Jets *are* collections of mesons, and sometimes baryons, in a fast frame. What's your point?

Comment: [Review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)).

Comment: @CosmasZachos maybe my question was not clear. Above a certain energy scale a pair of quarks will undergo a Parton shower and give rise to many hadrons in a jet. In low momentum transfer processes this will not happen and instead particles will decay to pairs of pions. The exact mechanism behind this is what I am asking

Comment: @annav the example I describe is of a beyond standard model particle (there are no right handed neutrinos in the SM) which will decay. but this is just an example to explain my question, it’s not really relevant

Comment: So for a 5π decay of your N going very fast you imagine there is a sharp distinction between two jets or not?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not sure what you mean by $5\pi$. If $N$ is light, the $W$ will be highly virtual and it's decay products will be very soft. In this case the $N$ will decay to $N \rightarrow \pi l$ (the two quarks from the $W$ decay immediately form a pion). If $N$ is heavy, the $W$ is closer to being on shell, then there is a larger momentum transfer to the two quarks, and they should be able to parton shower and form jets. The root of my question is trying to understand this interplay.

Comment: So you got it. The real  or timelike W will decay to as many hadrons are energetically allowed in its rest frame. The only interesting case is the latter, and the Parton shower operates.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have known this, my question is what the threshold is in terms of the QCD scale. E.g. how heavy does N need to be for the parton shower to occur.

Comment: This might well be a practical feature of jet algorithms. There is no abrupt, sharp transition. 5 pions will not distribute themselves uniformly, and their profile should morph to a 2-lobe configuration all things being equal, reflecting the hadronization of an original quark pair.  You are asking for a primer on hadronization!!???!!